# Getting a "must override superclass method" when compiling facebooks sample code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to compile the sample code from the facebook sdk.  Now I'm getting errors on all the
lines below @Override

example on the following lines

```
   @Override
   public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

I get a error that says:

> the method  startActivityForResult of type new must override super class type

could I just delete all the @Override

Comment: It means that the method is not overriding any method from superclass. Check the signature, it must match that of the superclass method, if the intention is to override it.

Comment: Deleting the annotation will probably work, but I'd check first if you need to be extending something that you're not extending, and check the method signature is exactly the same as in the superclass

Answer (score 1):

Whatever class you are extending is assumed to have a method declaration of startActivityForResult with exact return type and parameters. Check if you are following it. You can remove @Override and it will work, but by that you are saying, this method doesn't exist in your super class. Verify the class you perhaps extending. If this method is supposed to be invoked and you do not, something else will break.

Answer (score 1):

Method signature looks fine. You don't extend android.app.Activity class.

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
...